# upload file in other project directory in laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel-5, upload

I have a solution file that consist of two different projects. In one of the projects i have a code to upload the file and save it.

Currently the file is saved in same project directory that consist of code to upload the file.

I want to upload the file in other project directory.
Both project are same server

Is it possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Kind of hard to help you without any provided code though :)

Comment: Both code and location to save file must have same owner & group or location to save file should be public.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh yes both code and location are same owner

Comment: @Loek here is my code `$image = $request->file('profilePicture');
  $profilePicture = 'profile-'.time().'-'.rand(000000,999999).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();       
        $destinationPath = public_path('/profile-photos');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $profilePicture);`

Comment: If you hard code the path like that, why not just target your other project? `public_path('/../../other/public/path')`?

Comment: i want to upload  same file in both projects

Comment: Are you facing any issue @NabeelArbab? If yes, please post error details.